# How to read data for the next line which has same variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have the data like below, and I would like to get information of ID for each group ID. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks

```
ID GroupID Income age
1 1 5000 45
2 1 5000 27
3 2 3000 21
4 2 3000 35
5 2 3000 17
6 2 3000 16
```

I would like to get data like this:

```
groupID"1" ID"1" ID"2" income"5000"
groupID"2" ID"3" ID"4" ID"5" ID"5" income"3000"
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `data.table` and `splitstackshape`

```
library(data.table)
library(splitstackshape)
out <- setDT(df1)[, .(ID = toString(paste("ID", ID)), 
   Income = toString(paste("income", unique(Income)))),
        .(GroupID = paste('groupID', GroupID))]
cSplit(out, "ID", ", ")
#     GroupID      Income ID_1 ID_2 ID_3 ID_4
#1: groupID 1 income 5000 ID 1 ID 2 <NA> <NA>
#2: groupID 2 income 3000 ID 3 ID 4 ID 5 ID 6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:6, GroupID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
Income = c(5000L, 5000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L, 3000L), age = c(45L, 
27L, 21L, 35L, 17L, 16L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -6L))
```